# What is the reasoning for T to extend NodeJS.WritableStream and not Writable or WritableBase?

Tags: typescript

In `stream.d.ts` I found the definition below; however, it's not clear to me what the rationale could be for `T` to extend `NodeJS.WritableStream` instead of `Writable`.  Further, when looking at the `NodeJS.WritableStream` definition, I don't see where there is an overload for streams that are in `ObjectMode`.

```
class internal extends EventEmitter {
    pipe<T extends NodeJS.WritableStream>(
        destination: T,
        options?: {
            end?: boolean | undefined;
        },
    ): T;
    compose<T extends NodeJS.ReadableStream>(
        stream: T | ComposeFnParam | Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>,
        options?: { signal: AbortSignal },
    ): T;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a question you should the author of that code. Try blaming them in the git history, then open a discussion on the repo and ping them.